# How can I match the time zone of the Date: header of emails sent from Google Apps script to the time zone of the executing user?

Tags: date, google-apps-script, timezone, gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to send an email from a Google Apps Script.
I am using the example below but the time zone of the Date: header of sent email is different from the time zone of executing user.

```
function sendEmailTest() {
  var to = "test@example.com";
  var subject = "Test";
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var message = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
  GmailApp.sendEmail(to,subject,message);
}
```

The email sent from that script is as below.

```
From:     example@gmail.com
To:       test@example.com
Subject:  Test
Date:     Fri, 9 Oct 2020 16:51:01 -0700

2020/10/10 08:51:01
```

The time zone of the date of executing user that is in message body is UTC+09:00, but the time zone of the Date: header of email is UTC-07:00.

How can I match the time zone of the Date: header of emails sent from Google Apps script to the time zone of the executing user?

Comment: Session.getScriptTimeZone()

Comment: Welcome to [so].  Please add a brief description of your search / research efforts as is suggested in [ask] and clarify what you mean by "email with local time zone or specfic time zone" (your code is using JST)

Comment: You want to change `Fri, 9 Oct 2020 16:51:01 -0700` of `Date:     Fri, 9 Oct 2020 16:51:01 -0700` to the local time zone or specific time zone. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, in the current stage, I think that Date header in email cannot be customized by Gmail Service and Gmail API. Even when the custom date is given and the email is sent, it seems that the date header is automatically modified. I think that this might be the current answer for your question. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the Date field's timezone cannot be modified from the gmail api or the GmailApp in apps script. It "seems" to be based on the server the api connects to, which may be random. However, emails sent through `MailApp`'s timezone are fixed at `00:00` UTC. The following results of "raw" `Date: <date>` were seen during testing. Note that clients may display the timezone using any selected language or timezone. Only the raw `Date` field as shown  using "Show original" is recorded below:

- Emails sent directly from user interface:

  - Timezone offset at your current  browser timezone.
- Emails sent using `MailApp`:

  - Timezone offset fixed at `0000`. No offset. No timezone offset data is revealed.
- Emails sent using `GmailApp`:

  - Timezone offset fixed-probably random or the  timezone of the server currently accepting your request.(say `-0600`).
- Emails sent using `GmailAPI` using Google API explorer:

  - Timezone offset fixed-probably random or the  timezone of the server currently accepting your request.(say `-0600`).

The timezone offset did not change with

- IP address
- Language/location change at [Google settings](https://myaccount.google.com/language)
- Timezone of the script project as seen in File> Project properties > Timezone
- `Date` field set in the "raw" parameter in gmail api request body

Answer (score 2):

[RFC5322 Internet Message Format - 3.6.1 The Origination Date Field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.1) describes that:

> In any case, it is specifically not intended to convey the time that the message is actually transported, but rather the time at which the human or other creator of the message has put the message into its final form, ready for transport.

The time zone of `Date` header of the emails sent from Google Apps Script is given by the server running the Script.

Thus I can't modify the time zone of the Date: header to the time zone of the executing user.

But the recipient's client may display the time in the format and time zone local to them, so I don't have to worry about it.

Comment: You can test this. Change the recipient timezone manually(in OS) and see if the date header timezone changes?

Comment: @TheMaster I' ve test  changing OS time zone and the result is below.

Recipient OS time zone = UTC+00:00 -> Raw Date: header of the sent email = UTC-07:00 / Email client display date = UTC+00:00